# Admob interstitial ads non clickable

Tags: android, admob

I have encountered a weird behavior of Admob interstitial ads.

They are shown each time I leave the application, but for some reason the click doesn't work.

I found similar question on Stackoverflow:

[AdMob interstitial Ad is shown but can't click on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847178/admob-interstitial-ad-is-shown-but-cant-click-on-it)

but the solution provided there doesn't fix the problem.

Here is my snippet from manifest:

```
<!-- Google AdMob -->
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Has anyone else also noticed such problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: This problem occurred with me but it was solved automatically try to force stop the application and try again.

Comment: I have uploaded application several times with new APK so it was clean run each time.

Comment: which application is it?

Comment: By uploaded I meant uploaded to the device :-)

Comment: Show your code. NB you shouldn't be trying to show an intersitial when it is loaded or when your activity is finishing, either of those things is a bad user experience and possible Admob policy violation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found the solution to my problem.

It turned out that I was trying to show the interstitial ad after calling finish() method when leaving the application.

The ad itself was shown correctly, because it was loaded shortly after opening the application. But the context of the application was not available after calling finish() method, so nothing happened when I clicked on the ad.